# Mocking external clients (f.ex: AWS SDK SQS Client) when testing a symfony command

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, symfony5.4

[PHP] [Symfony 5.4] [Testing]

Hello!!
I am trying to add some test coverage to a symfony project. The service I am trying to test is a symfony CLI command.
The setup looks something like this:

`FetchMessageCommand.php` (<- starting point of the flow)

```
class FetchMessageCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        KernelInterface $kernel,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        AWSSQSManager $awsSQSManager,
        //.... some other dependencies
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->awsSQSManager = $awsSQSManager;
        // ...
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        try {
            // ... some more business logic

            $this->awsSQSManager->processMessages();

            // ... some more business logic
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error('An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return Command::FAILURE;
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

`AWSSQSManager.php`

```
class AWSSQSManager
{    
    public function __construct(
        AWSSQSClientInterface $AWSSQSClient,
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        // ... some other dependencies
    ) {
        $this->AWSSQSClient = $AWSSQSClient;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        // ...
    }

    public function processMessages()
    {
        $this->logger->info("fetching message data..");

        $queueUrl = $this->AWSSQSClient->getQueueUrl($this->removalQueueName);
        // .... some other logic
    }
    // ... some other code
}
```

`AWSSQSClient.php` (<- this is the actual service injected by framework to replace AWSSQSClientInterface above in AWSSQSManager class)

```
class AWSSQSClient implements AWSSQSClientInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        SqsClient $client,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        string $accountId
    ) {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->accountId = $accountId;
    }

    public function getQueueUrl($queueName)
    {
        try {
            $requestParams = [
                'QueueName' => $queueName,
                'QueueOwnerAWSAccountId' => $this->accountId
            ];

            $queueUrlResult = $this->client->getQueueUrl($requestParams);
            $queueUrl = $queueUrlResult->get('QueueUrl');

            return $queueUrl;
        } catch (AwsException $e) {
            $this->exception($e, "GET getQueueUrl failed");
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // ... more functions and code
}
```

*Of course I have omitted imports, variable declarations and some irrelevant codes from here, but should be good enough to give context. Feel free to ask for details if needed.*

Now, my objective is mock `SqsClient` class which is exposed by AWS SDK to prevent my test from making an actual call to the AWS.
And this is how I am trying to mock it:

`FetchMessageCommand.php`

```
class FetchMessageCommand extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected ?Application $application = null;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        self::bootKernel();

        $container = static::getContainer();

        if (null === $this->application) {
            $this->application = new Application(self::$kernel);
        }

        $sqsClient = $this->getMockBuilder(SqsClient::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->disableArgumentCloning()
            ->disableOriginalClone()
            ->disableAutoload()
            ->disableProxyingToOriginalMethods()
            ->setConstructorArgs([])
            ->addMethods(['receiveMessage', 'getQueueUrl', 'sendMessage', 'deleteMessage', 'GetQueueUrl'])
            ->getMock();

        $sqsClient->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getQueueUrl')
            ->willReturn('https://example.com');

        $sqsClient->expects($this->once())
            ->method('GetQueueUrl')
            ->willReturn('https://example.com');

       // .... more expectations for rest of the methods

        $container->set(SqsClient::class, $sqsClient);
    }

    public function testMessageDataRequest()
    {
        $command = $this->application->find('fetch:message');

        // now call the command
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute([]);

        $commandTester->assertCommandIsSuccessful();
    }
```

When the test begins (with debug mode), the FetchMessageCommand gets the mocked version of `SqsClient` but the instance of `AWSSQSManager` -> `AWSSQSClient` continue to use the `SqsClient` from original SDK and endup making an actual call to the AWS.

From what I learned so far (after googling and reading docs), the container is getting initialised and services in `AWSSQSClient` are getting auto-wired before the mocks are generated and that's how symfony works.
So, my stupid question is, is there a way to actually make it work such that my test don't make an actual call to AWS? Or is my apporach completely wrong?

I can of course change my approach and instead of testing the entire command, just focus my test on `AWSSQSManager` but that beats the purpose of integration test or application test and the business logic in `FetchMessageCommand` will get leftout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of reading and debugging, I couldn't find a better way to handle this and therefore ended up with a slightly different approach. Not sure if this aligns with the principles but is worked for me.

Due to the limitation of how symfony auto-wiring of services work, the only way to make sure the mocks are being injected in the required class, I had to create a partial mock of each class in the dependency tree until SQSClient.
So. in my case that was first mocking the `AWSSQSClient` (with `SQSClientMock`), and then passing this to `AWSSQSManager` mock.
Of course, I also had to also pass all the constructor arguments manually.

Here's how my `setUp` function in `FetchMessageCommand` test file ended up like:

```
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        self::bootKernel();

        $container = static::getContainer();

        $sqsClientMock = Mockery::mock(SqsClient::class)->makePartial();
        $sqsClientMock->shouldReceive('getQueueUrl')->andReturn('https://example.com');
        $container->set(SqsClient::class, $sqsClientMock);

        $entityManager = $container->get(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $logger = $container->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        //... other dependencies required by AWSSQSClient and AWSSQSManager classes

        $awsSQSClientMock = Mockery::mock(AWSSQSClient::class, [
            $sqsClientMock,
            $logger,
            // .... other dependencies
        ])->makePartial();
        $container->set(AWSSQSClient::class, $awsSQSClientMock);

        $awsSQSManagerMock = Mockery::mock(AWSSQSManager::class, [
            $awsSQSClientMock,
            $entityManager,
            $logger,
            // ... other dependencies
        ])->makePartial();
        $container->set(AWSSQSManager::class, $awsSQSManagerMock);
    }
```